# TypeScript: use a nested, constant object definition with a type for inferred type definition

Tags: typescript

I have a static object definition that I would like to ensure conforms to a type but also be able to use the constant definition for inferred types. For example:

```js
const TREE_BRANCH_TYPES = ['Type1', 'Type2'] as const;

type TreeBranchType = typeof TREE_BRANCH_TYPES[number];
type TreeRoot = Record<TreeBranchType, TreeBranch>;
type TreeBranch = { leaves: readonly TreeLeaf[] };
type TreeLeaf = { name: string };

const tree: TreeRoot = {
    Type1: {
        leaves: [
            { name: 'Type1-Leaf1' },
            { name: 'Type1-Leaf2' },
        ]
    },
    Type2: {
        leaves: [
            { name: 'Type2-Leaf1' },
            { name: 'Type2-Leaf2' },
        ]
    }
} as const;

type TreeLeafName = typeof tree[TreeBranchType]['leaves'][number]['name'];

function findLeaf(type: TreeBranchType, name: TreeLeafName): TreeLeaf | undefined {
    return tree[type].leaves.find(leaf => leaf.name === name);
}
```

Given the above, the compiler will require `tree` to conform to the `TreeRoot` definition, but `TreeLeafName` is interpreted by the compiler as `type TreeLeafName = string`.

However, if I remove the type from `tree` (i.e. `const tree = { ... };`), then `TreeLeafName` is recognized by the compiler as `type TreeLeafName = "Type1-Leaf1" | "Type1-Leaf2" | "Type2-Leaf1" | "Type2-Leaf2"`.

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds? Type safety on the `tree` constant definition and type safety of the inferred `TreeLeafName` type?

Comment: @jcalz sorry. Missed a line when copy + pasting

Comment: Yet another use case for `satisfies`! I just love this new feature of TypeScript: `const tree = {} as const satisfies TreeRoot;`

Comment: The `findLeaf()` implementation being in error is almost certainly out of scope for the question as asked, since that would have happened anyway if you remove the type from `tree`, and you're not asking about it.  Could you [edit] the question so that issue doesn't arise (say by just making it a declaration and not implementing it)?

Comment: @jcalz wouldn't casting or just setting a local variable in the function solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this with TS4.9 and above is to use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to check that a value is assignable to a type without widening/upcasting it to that type:

```
const tree = {
    Type1: {
        leaves: [
            { name: 'Type1-Leaf1' },
            { name: 'Type1-Leaf2' },
        ]
    },
    Type2: {
        leaves: [
            { name: 'Type2-Leaf1' },
            { name: 'Type2-Leaf2' },
        ]
    }
} as const satisfies TreeRoot;

type TreeLeafName = typeof tree[TreeBranchType]['leaves'][number]['name'];
// type TreeLeafName = "Type1-Leaf1" | "Type1-Leaf2" | "Type2-Leaf1" | "Type2-Leaf2"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgJQKJIPoCEEEEByBhACVTgE0AFJAZRgF4YBtAIjgE8AHAUwEZGAaGZuw4AmRgF0YAQwgxQkKAG4AUEqhD4AJw4d0GyWGAALVp1ow1nEADN4yNJlyFi5KvTABXALYAjDhrHKFhya2gggILB0CBygGgAmADxwWjp6BsZC-MnauvpGAHyB6tmpeYZmAN4wADYckgBuHBAAXDBaknHg1SwhHAAydVb0EgC+RaYlA5I2dFVgkp4crdAaAJZgAOYwYypy0OYplUowJ-BCXK0Vx6c3tQ1NrfTXNy8wcwtLMADkJtwAtFMrFwvtteM9Xqd3otWj9zgDBsIQSMwRCYGJwcjwb9hJdwbc6o0Wgw8RCoZ9YZxhPDpsDQSTXmSYdjqVZEXTUeibiMlCMpDI9rAIJIoKsIFZVk1emEIspVMUUoCcB8zEFrAdtPQSrl0r8xPQvndCV89R4fH49V95otjcoAPS28zy7SK5V0QScLgsngwAA+Al+nsBol9-qEVMB3r97pELNEKjiMWqki0MCs7gMIvAqfWcUBAAogq0tWkjL9+FbPpNBkrFgBKIsKwYh9MJ8VgDhxO0O1aeNi1RZgKDC1ZZ0UwEDuWBqiCgThAA)

Comment: One thing to note is that you will still need to cast your constant to the intended type to conform to the `satisfied` type (e.g. `(tree as TreeRoot)[type].leaves...`)